# Cakephp Update multiple records or create new one if id doesn't exist in database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

hello I have an edit form which displays the input fields.I am displaying the data from database in those fields so user can edit them. And also there is a button which ask to add new field. I am able to edit multiple fields but the problem is how can I create a new field in database if there is no existing id of the record. 
Note: For the new field I am sending `0` id so that I can check in cakephp that it has a new field.

```
foreach ($exp as $k => $v) {
  $dat[$k]["prp_id"] = $prpid;
  $dat[$k]["exp_company"] = $v['company'];
  $dat[$k]["position"] = $v['position'];
  $dat[$k]["exp_id"] = $v['exp_id'];
}

$this->Experience->saveAll($dat, array('conditions' => array('exp_id' => $v['exp_id'])));
```

This is updating all the fields. Btw I am also not sure why its working correctly as I am here `$v['exp_id']` sending only one value because its out of the loop but it is working perfectly meaning I can be able to multiple fields which I am not sure how. So In the end I have two problems. One is to create a new record if `exp_id` is `0` and second is why my this code works good for updating records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 foreach ($exp as $k => $v) {
   $dat[$k]["prp_id"] = $prpid;
   $dat[$k]["exp_company"] = $v['company'];
   $dat[$k]["position"] = $v['position'];

   if ($v['exp_id'] != 0) {
     $dat[$k]["exp_id"] = $v['exp_id'];
   }
 }

 $this->Experience->saveAll($dat);
```

Comment: Its not updating it. It creates new records

Comment: may i see debug result of $dat array ..i wanna see if you have to check that condition within foreach loop.